# Typescript asynchronous call with mariadb

Tags: typescript, methods, async-await

What I am doing wrong?
I declared this method. I am not shure if it is correct.

```
async getTutorials() : Promise<Tutorial[]> {
  
  return await mariadb.createConnection(Config.db)
    .then(conn => {
      conn.query('select * from tutorial')
        .then(rows => {
          rows.forEach(row => {
            console.log(row);
          });
          conn.end();
          return new Promise(rows);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //handle query error
          return [];
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      //handle connection error
      return [];
    });   
  }
}
```

Then I would like to call this method within that method.

```
export const getTutorials: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    let tutorials = await tutorialService.getTutorials();
    console.log(tutorials);
    res.status(200).json({tutorials});
}
```

The console log of this method prints an undefined object. The log of the first method prints correctly the objects.
I do not know how to transfer the array from the first to the second method.

Answer (score 1):

Take some time understanding promises! You should not be catching (and ignoring) errors, and `await` is not needed if you use `.then()`. You also don't ever need to use `new Promise` from your `then` callback.

The 2 core issues is that you're using a nested promise (also not a good idea, you want to chain), and the inner promise is not returned to the outer promise. The other issue is that you pass the result of the query (`rows`) to `new Promise()`, but `new Promise` expects to receive a callback, not a result. You might have intended to use `Promise.resolve()` here, but it's not needed at all.

Fixing all those issues results in this:

```js
async getTutorials() : Promise<Tutorial[]> {
  
  return mariadb.createConnection(Config.db)
    .then(conn => {
      return conn.query('select * from tutorial');
    })
    .then(rows => {
      conn.end();
      return rows;
    })
 
  }
}
```

However, with await this can be simplified further:

```js
async getTutorials() : Promise<Tutorial[]> {
  const conn = await mariadb.createConnection(Config.db);
  const rows = await conn.query('select * from tutorial');
  conn.end();
  return rows;
}
```